# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined when using array value to get javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a config.js and a js file to get data from config.js.

I have also checked the value of urlArry[i] is actually as follow:
array 1 : home
array 2 : pageone
array 3 : pagetwo

The problem occur when i try to use test.urlArry[i].url to get the url path in config.js.

However the problem does not persist when i hardcode test.home.url, it will be able to get the value from config.js

config.js code as follow:

```js
var test = {
 home: {
  url: '../home/'
 },
    pageone: {
  url: '../pageone/'
 },
    pagetwo: {
  url: '../pagetwo/'
 }
}
```

common js file as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var sampleUrl = 'home/pageone/pagetwo';
  
  var urlArry = sampleUrl.split('/');
  
  var breadCrumbFullHtml;

  for (i = 1; i < urlArry.length; i++) {
    
breadCrumbFullHtml += '<li><a href="'+ test.urlArry[i].url+'"></a></li>';
  }
  
  $('.breadcrumb').html(breadCrumbFullHtml);
}
```

Comment: You have not defined `urlArry` in `test` object thus the error, May be you need `test[urlArry[i]][i].url`

Comment: Hi Satpal, Thanks for the help! I manage to fix it with your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it could be helpful to you  try instead of this `test.urlArry[index].url`   =>  `test[urlArray[index]].url`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var test = {
 home: {
  url: '../home/'
 },
    pageone: {
  url: '../pageone/'
 },
    pagetwo: {
  url: '../pagetwo/'
 }
}

 var sampleUrl = 'home/pageone/pagetwo';
  
  var urlArry = sampleUrl.split('/');
  
  var breadCrumbFullHtml;
breadCrumbFullHtml ="<ul>";
  for (i = 0; i < urlArry.length; i++) {
    //console.log(test[urlArry[i]])
 breadCrumbFullHtml += 
 '<li><a href="'+ test[urlArry[i]].url+'">'+test[urlArry[i]].url+'</a></li>';
  }
  breadCrumbFullHtml += "</ul>";
  $('.breadcrumb').html(breadCrumbFullHtml);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumb"></div>
```